# Rails 3 HABTM yields ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, associations

I have a legacy Rails 3 application and I'm trying to set up a simple HABTM relationship between two models:  VolunteerCircle and User.  I have this same association in two other models.

The associations are as follows:

VolunteerCircle model:

```
class VolunteerCircle < ActiveRecord::Base 
    #...

    has_and_belongs_to_many   :users 

    # ...
end
```

User model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  #...

  has_and_belongs_to_many :volunteer_circles

  #...
end
```

And here is the migration:

```
class CreateVolunteerCirclesUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :volunteer_circles_users, id: false do |t|
      t.belongs_to :volunteer_circle, index: true
      t.belongs_to :user, index: true
    end
  end
end
```

When I call #users on a VolunteerCircle object (or vice-versa), Rails coughs up an ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy object.

The volunteer_circles_users table looks right to me in the database.  What am I missing here?

Also, I am aware of the superiority of HABTMT.  Circumstances beyond my control dictate HABTM here.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having a hard time trying to find the error here.. But maybe some of these will help you:

I think you are missing the multiple field index:

```
add_index : volunteer_circles_users, [:volunteer_circles_id, :user_id]
add_index : volunteer_circles_users, [:user_id, :volunteer_circles_id]
```

And the create_join_table creates it in alphabetical order, so it would be *user_volunteer_circles* instead. So, maybe you could need to do something like:

```
class VolunteerCircle < ActiveRecord::Base 
    has_and_belongs_to_many :users, :join_table => : volunteer_circles_users
end
```

Hope it helps..

Comment: You nailed it with the note about alphabetical order.  Thanks for the information!